# How can I bulk rename files using PowerShell?

Tags: tfs, powershell

I'm trying to recursively rename a bunch of [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) folders using `tf rename`, [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) and a regular expression but I'm having some issues with PowerShell as I haven't spent much time with it.  This is what I've put together so far to replace a leading `5` with `2.3.2` but it isn't working:

```
dir | foreach { tf rename $_ { $_.Name -replace '^5', '2.3.2' } }
```

Actual result:

```
Unrecognized command option 'encodedCommand'.
Unrecognized command option 'encodedCommand'.
Unrecognized command option 'encodedCommand'.
Unrecognized command option 'encodedCommand'.
...etc.
```

Update:

I got a little closer by doing the following instead:

```
dir | foreach { $newname = $_.Name -replace "^5", "2.3.2"; tf rename $_ $newname }
```

My next goal is to make this recurse subdirectories but this seems a bit more challenging (changing it to `dir -recurse` makes it quit after the parent folders for some reason).

Comment: Don't know the answer, but a good question.  :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would first filter by 5* so you only process names that start with 5.  Also, in this case since tf.exe isn't a PowerShell cmdlet, you don't want to use a scriptblock to determine a new name. Just use a grouping expression like so:

```
dir -filter 5* | foreach { tf rename $_ ($_.Name -replace '^5', '2.3.2')}
```

BTW, when you are trying to debug parameter passing to a native EXE like this it is immensely helpful to use the echoargs.exe utilty from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).  This is what it told me about your original approach:

```
6# dir -filter 5* | foreach { echoargs rename $_ { $_.Name -replace '^5', '2.3.2' } }
Arg 0 is <rename>
Arg 1 is <5foo.txt>
Arg 2 is <-encodedCommand>
Arg 3 is <IAAkAF8ALgBOAGEAbQBlACAALQByAGUAcABsAGEAYwBlACAAJwBeADUAJwAsACAAJwAyAC4AMwAuADIAJwAgAA==>
Arg 4 is <-inputFormat>
Arg 5 is <xml>
Arg 6 is <-outputFormat>
Arg 7 is <text>
```

Answer (score 4):

Notes:

- TFS has [native cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) -- no need for tf.exe in most cases.
- The time complexity of workspace operations depends on the number of pending renames already in the workspace.  In TFS 2005/2008 it's significantly worse than linear.  Bottom line, you should really consider batching up renames into multiple checkins if you have a large # of items, otherwise every single "tf rename" (or New-TfsPendingChange -Rename if using the cmdlets) will start taking minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dir . | foreach { $newname = $_.Name -replace "^5", "2.3.2"; tf rename $_ $newname }
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the above commands requires the tf.exe to have been aliased as 'tf'.. or it did on my machine at least.

Run this command:

```
Set-Alias tf "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe"
```

Update the path to tf.exe as appropriate

Also consider adding the line to your profile for future use

```
notepad $PROFILE
```