# How to pass Properties to jar from Powershell?

Tags: java, powershell, jar, properties

I've been using Powershell-1.0 for command line needs for a while, instead of cmd.exe. Unfortunately, there are still some caveats when using Java. I need to pass a property to a jar, like that:

```
java -jar -Duser.language=en any.jar
```

This line works fine in cmd.exe, but not in Powershell as it searches for another jar:

> Unable to access jarfile user.language=en

Using quotes doesn't help.

Is it doable in Powershell-1.0, or do I miss something in Java?

Comment: it is good that you try it out in cmd.exe, I was just 'troubleshooting' my problems elsewhere when below command occured to me the class path is not available. Who would think the powershell was the cause. `java -Djasypt.encryptor.password=pass -jar my.jar`

Answer (score 32):

Take a look at my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267967/how-can-i-bulk-rename-files-using-powershell/1269429#1269429).  Note how you can use echoargs.exe to diagnose these sort of problems.  Most likely the fix would be to quote the parameter e.g.:

```
java -jar "-Duser.language=en" any.jar
```

You can test that using echoargs (from [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com)):

```
echoargs -jar "-Duser.language=en" any.jar
Arg 0 is <-jar>
Arg 1 is <-Duser.language=en>
Arg 2 is <any.jar>
```

Answer (score 15):

Using quotes works fine for me in PowerShell on Windows 7.

```
java "-Dmy.property=value" -jar myjar.jar
```

Be careful: the jar name must be placed right after `-jar`, and arguments placed after `-jar myjar.jar` will be passed to the program *inside* the jarFile.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching instead using the following pattern:

```
java -Duser.language=en -jar any.jar
```

That assumes that user.language is meant as a system property. If you meant it as a command line argument, change that to:

```
java -jar any.jar -Duser.language=en
```

I am actually surprised that the command line you mentioned works at all outside of powershell (though I have confirmed that it works fine for me too, even on Linux) and it is also a little strange that things would work differently inside and outside of powershell.

From `java -help`:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]                 
           (to execute a class)                        
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]          
           (to execute a jar file)                     
where options include:
...
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
...
```

So basically you should always put the JAR filename directly after the `-jar` command line option, and any JVM options (such as setting system properties with `-D`) before.

Comment: PowerShell does something weird to the -D-options passed to java, so this will not work. See Keith Hill's answer.

Comment: @Johannes Powershell's demented mangling of the command line aside, my answer still stands, that the JAR name must *always* be directly after the `-jar` on the command line (which is not the case in the original question)