# Powershell not passing arguments to cmake properly

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Powershell as my main shell in Windows 10. Most of the time it works well, but some things cause me to move back to the old Command Prompt, and I wish they wouldn't.

I'm trying to use cmake to create a Visual Studio solution. Here is the command line that works properly in command prompt (broken into lines for clarity)

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64 
         -DBOOST_ROOT=d:\boost\1_59_0 
         -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=d:\boost\1_59_0\lib64
```

When I run the same command from Powershell, cmake complains I did not specify BOOST_ROOT.

I tried using `& cmake ...`, I tried putting quotes around all the -D's (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520376/871910)) - nothing works. I just can't make Powershell pass the command line as is to cmake.

Is there a way to tell Powershell to pass the text following 'cmake' directly to cmake without any further processing? Note that I can't put quotes around all the arguments, since they already have quotes in them (-G...). If I put single quotes around everything - it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is that your full command in the question? I've tried your command substituing cmake for a program called echoargs which just prints back the arguments it gets. It appears powershell passes all the arguments correctly.

Comment: did you tried the escape argument `--%` ? ( for PS V3)

Comment: @DanL, yes, this is my entire command. Works from Command Prompt, fails from Powershell.

Comment: Can you try with this `Start-Process cmake  -ArgumentList "-G ""Visual Studio 14 2015"" -A x64 -DBOOST_ROOT=d:\boost\1_59_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=d:\boost\1_59_0\lib64"`

Comment: I had to add the -NoNewWindow flag, but yes - it works. And waits for me to press ENTER when it's done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starting external programs in PowerShell it's best to use `Start-Process` with its `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
Start-Process cmake -ArgumentList "-G ""Visual Studio 14 2015"" -A x64 -DBOOST_ROOT=d:\boost\1_59_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=d:\boost\1_59_0\lib64" -NoNewWindow
```

More info on this Cmdlet can be found on the [Microsoft help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or by using the following command in PowerShell:

```
Get-Help Start-Process -ShowWindow
```

Comment: Great! Now I need to make this into a handy function that saves me from typing -NoNewWindow, -Wait, -ArgumentList and the quotes.

Comment: @zmbq How exactly did you instruct `cmake` to use parent folder (`cmake ..` from your question) with `Start-Process` method?