# Error: Could not find or load main class .library.path=

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to run DynamoDB locally, with the instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

I've downloaded the zip file, and unzipped everything into a folder.

I'm on Windows 10.

In Powershell, in that directory when I run:
`java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

I get:

`Error: Could not find or load main class .library.path=..DynamoDBLocal_lib`

I've read this which is very similar - closest I could find but it didn't help:
[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949890/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path)

**I don't think the issue is that it cannot find the class, it is that it doesn't know what library.path means.**

I have java installed:
`C:\Dynamo> java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)`

In my PATH I have C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath which I think is correct.

Do I need the JDK? not just JRE? Am I doing something else wrong?

I think that the path in the example may not be correct for windows, but I don't think that is the problem, I have tried dozens of different paths, but they all say the same thing.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We found that PowerShell misinterprets the `-Djava.library.path` parameter.
Enclosing either the parameter name or the entire name & value fixed the issue in our case.

`java -D"java.library.path"=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

or

`java "-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib" -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

The answers to this question also helped
[How to pass Properties to jar from Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518698/how-to-pass-properties-to-jar-from-powershell)

Answer (score 10):

Tried one last time before posting the question, this time with just a normal command prompt rather than powershell and it works. The path in the example worked fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your question and answer! this is exactly the same issue i was having and ur answer helped me find the solution.

Comment: Please see @Mike's answer. His answer provides a solution rather than a workaround.