# How to disable/override PowerShell dot notation

Tags: powershell

Commands in PowerShell are almost like Bash, but the dot notation expansion is creating a lot of work for me. Currently I have to wrap a lot of command parameters in quotes:

`.\mvnw.cmd -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgroupId=com.zippo -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=test-1.0.jar`

becomes

`.\mvnw.cmd -D"maven.repo.local"=".m2/repository" deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgroupId="com.zippo" -DartifactId=test -Dversion="1.0" -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="test-1.0.jar"`

How can I disable dot notation, or override the dot operator, replace it with something else, etc.?

Comment: Give the full path of the `mvnw.cmd` instead of the Dot. And I would recommend using [GRADLE WRAPPER](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) instead of maven wrapper.

Comment: PowerShell offers the stop-parsing symbol (`--%`) for this : `.\mwnw.cmd --%` and then the rest of your command line.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood this question. I thought this question was to disable autocomplete adding a .\.

Comment: I've added a new question at https://superuser.com/q/1741125 which exactly matches what I opened the bounty for here.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15541

Comment: I originally posted a bounty for this question because, being new to PowerShell, I had confused it with [another issue](https://superuser.com/q/1741125). But now this issue is starting to bite me. (I have to change the way I invoke Java just to use PowerShell??! Incredible.) So I'm glad I put a bounty on this question after all. Too bad there is no real workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I disable dot notation?

- The problem isn't dot notation, **it is a *bug* in how PowerShell parses arguments to be passed to *external programs***:

  - A token such as `-foo.bar` is unexpectedly broken into *two* arguments, `-foo` and `.bar` - see [GitHub issue #6291](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291) (accidental duplicate: [GitHub issue #15541](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15541)); this is but one among [several related bugs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+parameter+parsing%2Fpassing+in%3Atitle), present up to at least PowerShell 7.3.6.
- ***Escaping* or *quoting*** is indeed needed to **work around this problem**, but you can **simplify** it by **`` ` ``-escaping the initial `-` of each affected argument** or by **enclosing each *as a whole* in `'...'`** (or `"..."`, if you need string interpolation):

  ```bash
  # `-escape the initial - of all affected arguments.
  .\mvnw.cmd `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus `-DgroupId=com.zippo -DartifactId=test `-Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar `-Dfile=test-1.0.jar

  # Alternative: Quote the affected arguments.
  .\mvnw.cmd '-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository' deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus '-DgroupId=com.zippo' -DartifactId=test '-Dversion=1.0' -Dpackaging=jar '-Dfile=test-1.0.jar'
  ```

  - If you don't want to have to think about which specific arguments may be affected, quote them *all*, which - combined with the fact that you can pass arguments as an *array* of strings, using `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - can be used to make a long command more readable, by spreading it across multiple lines:

    ```bash
    .\mvnw.cmd @(
      '-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository'
      'deploy:deploy-file' 
      '-Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/'
      '-DrepositoryId=nexus' 
      '-DgroupId=com.zippo'
      '-DartifactId=test'
      '-Dversion=1.0'
      '-Dpackaging=jar'
      '-Dfile=test-1.0.jar'
    )
    ```

**Alternatives**:

- You can **use `--%`**, the [stop-parsing token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), which obviates the need for quoting, but **note its many limitations**, notably the inability to (directly) incorporate PowerShell variables and expressions into the command - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375) for details.

  ```bash
  # --% passes the remainder of the command line as-is to the target program
  .\mvnw.cmd --% -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgroupId=com.zippo -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=test-1.0.jar
  ```
- You can **call via `cmd /c`**, in which case you can quote your *entire command line*, which avoids the parsing bug (though note that the command specified in the string must then satisfy `cmd.exe`'s syntax rules; they can differ from PowerShell's, albeit not in this case):

  ```bash
  cmd /c '.\mvnw.cmd -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://zippo:8081/repository/grinch/ -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgroupId=com.zippo -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=test-1.0.jar'
  ```

Comment: So after using PowerShell quite a while and getting to know it better, whatever benefits it brings (parameter parsing is great—except [when it's not](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18387)), it seems to negate with basic blunders such as this one. I had started to [build bigger things with PowerShell](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/01/04/fix-manning-epub), but if I have to change the way I've invoked Java since 1997 or so, then I've realized that I might as well use Git Bash or WSL, deal with a few Bash quirks, and be happy with something that runs basically everywhere.

Comment: @GarretWilson, I share your frustration that such basic bugs have been allowed to linger for years. However, note that even if they were fixed, there will still be - unavoidable - cases where command lines behave differently than in other shells, given the different escape character (`\`` vs. `\`) and PowerShell's additional metacharacters (e.g., `@`). Unlike the annoying bugs, these difference are the unavoidable price you pay for, in part, PowerShell's Windows heritage (escape char.), but, on the plus side, for its superior argument-passing capabilities and type support.

Comment: I hear what you're saying @mklement0, and if these were corner cases or rare cases or cases that traded far superior functionality for a little twist in syntax, I would completely understand. But breaking the most common day-to-day use cases in exchange for buggy "superior" functionality gets frustrating after a while. Thanks for the empathy.

Comment: I thought I would be clever and at least add some one-off `$PROFILE` functions to work around this for certain commands such as [invoking Java with system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520376), e.g. `java -jar -Dfoo.bar=test example.jar`. I tried `function java {java.exe --% @args}` but that didn't work. Neither did `function java {java.exe --% $args}`. Any ideas?

Comment: @GarretWilson, unfortunately, you cannot solve this via a function to which you pass individual arguments, because the problem is how those individual arguments are parsed (except if you quote them). If you want a helper function, make it accept a _single string_ with a command line for `cmd /c` / `sh -c`, and invoke it via the latter.

Comment: I appreciate that you've continued to think about this. But I'm pretty much a lost cause now. All these PowerShell bugs and issues piled up (not even mentioning that it takes several seconds just to get a PowerShell prompt). I finally threw in the towel switched to Git Bash several months ago, and I'm liking my decision better every day. Plus my scripts are truly cross platform now. PowerShell was a great idea that, like many great ideas Microsoft took and ran with, is now just a hobbled, buggy, inconsistent weight to tie me down and add more irritations to my day.

Comment: @GarretWilson, I hear you with respect to the frustration over long-standing bugs not getting fixed, as well as historical warts that cannot get fixed, because doing so would break backward compatibility. That said, PowerShell's scripting language is vastly superior to that of Bash and virtually all other shells, and another pain point - the lack of raw byte handling in the pipeline, is finally getting addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features#psnativecommandpreservebytepipe (only an _experimental_ feature at this point).

Comment: "… PowerShell's scripting language is vastly superior to that of Bash and virtually all other shell …." That's probably true, but it's missing the point. Most of the things I want to do in the shell are relatively simple things, which PowerShell gunks up. If I have a task that needs a "vastly superior" language, I wouldn't even be using a shell scripting language at that point—that's what Python, Node, and Java are for. Heck, even Rust. But for the simple things I want a shell script for, PowerShell lets me down. But I stress again I appreciate the input and help you've given me, @mklement0.