# How can I generate a parent POM file using Maven?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a [Multi-Module Project with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module). I'm stuck in the first step *6.1* of the post.

```bash
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.baeldung -DartifactId=parent-project
```

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73659430/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally realized that my PowerShell environment will interpret into the wrong command. So the correct command in PowerShell should be:

```
mvn archetype:generate '-DgroupId=com.baeldung' '-DartifactId=parent-project'
```

If I put the original command in a **Command Prompt**, it will not produce any error.

See also: *[How to disable/override PowerShell dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794981/how-to-disable-override-powershell-dot-notation/73650127#73650127)*

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything. You may not have run the command line command correctly.

The same command works for me:

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.baeldung -DartifactId=parent-project`

Result:

```
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\dev\testing
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.baeldung
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.baeldung
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: parent-project
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.baeldung
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: C:\dev\testing\parent-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45.571 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-09T11:16:06+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Check also the version of mvn you have installed

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12
Default locale: no_NO, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: I think it’s possibly the PowerShell issue.