# On powershell for linux the print out of a maven command has additional characters

Tags: linux, powershell, maven, special-characters, maven-help-plugin

I am using powershell 7.4.1 on Linux and Windows.

And I used following commands to get the current target version of my maven project.

```
$version = mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression='project.version' -q -DforceStdout
```

or

```
$version = mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive -q
```

if I print the `$version` it looks like that they are working on both platform and are returning `2.68.0-SNAPSHOT`

However I experienced some problems on my Linux system. So after digging I found the cause in the commands above. Because if I print the output as hex values to what that string contains.

I get on Linux

```
32 2E 36 38 2E 30 2D 53 4E 41 50 53 48 4F 54 20 1B 5B 30 6D
```

on Windows

```
32 2E 36 38 2E 30 2D 53 4E 41 50 53 48 4F 54
```

So does anybody know why there are `20 1B 5B 30 6D` this additional characters on my Linux system. And how can I get rid of them (except replacing them afterwards)?

Comment: What happens when you add in `-Dstyle.color=never` to the command?

Comment: @g00se I use ``pwsh -c '([Convert]::ToHexString([system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getBytes(((mvn help:evaluate `-Dexpression="project.version" -q `-DforceStdout `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" `-Dstyle.color="never"))`` this command for testing. And the ouput changed to `1B5B306D322E36382E302D534E415053484F541B5B306D` So there are even more.

Comment: Hehe. I'm not quite sure what's going on there but it seems that the 'extra characters' might be an ANSI escape sequence (normally used for color). And (though not really knowing Powershell) I'm not sure that's 100% correct. I think you can lose those double quotes for simplification

Comment: What I'd try to find is the Powershell equivalent of the sort of thing Unix `strace` can do, namely showing the exact commands that are *actually* being executed. It's conceivable that the relatively troublesome command is being wrongly interpreted. You could also try putting it in a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're receiving contains [ANSI/VT escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are typically used for producing colored terminal output.

If the intent is to receive *data only*, as in your case, these escape sequences are undesired.

- If available, it is best to ask an external program such as `mvn` not to produce colored output to begin with.

  - According to the [Maven CLI Options Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html), you can use `-B` (or `--batch-mode`) to disable coloring;<sup>[1]</sup> e.g.:

    ```bash
    $version = 
      mvn -B help:evaluate -Dexpression='project.version' -q -DforceStdout
    ```

    - **Caveat**: As a general syntax requirement, due to an unfortunate, long-standing PowerShell bug, arguments that contain `.` in the unquoted part following the parameter name must have their initial `-` escaped as `` `- ``.
      For instance, `-Dexec.executable='echo'` must be passed as
      `` `-Dexec.executable='echo' `` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73650127/45375) for background information.
- If not, you can remove these escape sequences with the help of the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated), available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only (v7.2+):

  - A simple example: The sample string contains escape sequences that render the word "green" in green; the `.ToString('PlainText')` method call strips (removes) these escape sequences.

    ```bash
    # Sample input string that contains ANSI/VT escape sequences.
    $stringWithEscapeSequences = "It ain't easy being $([char]27)[32mgreen$([char]27)[m."

    # -> "It ain't easy being green."
    [System.Management.Automation.Internal.StringDecorated]::new(
      $stringWithEscapeSequences
    ).ToString('PlainText')
    ```

---

<sup>[1] The [documentation link](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html) is to the *current stable* version of `mvn` (via a `/current/` segment in the URL, which turns into the concrete version number in the browser), which is v3.9.6 as of this writing. The same page is available down to [version 3.1.0](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html) and shows the `-B` (`--batch-mode`) option too; whether even earlier versions also support it, I don't know - `mvn --help` may reveal that.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. With this it works. Note: `-B` (or `--batch`) is available since Maven 3.9. I am on an older version for now. So this is not an option.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Christian. I mistyped the long option name (since fixed in the answer): it should be `--batch-mode`. The docs actually suggest that the option is available since at least v3.1 - please see the footnote I've added to the answer for details.

Comment: You are right. Sorry then my memories played tricks on me. Thx for clarification.